# Hither is an examination of prudence

Tags: poetry, literature

What line is hidden behind the questionmarks?

> Hither is an examination of prudence.
>   Prudence is not ultimately checked at college.
>   ??????  ??????  ??????  ??????  ??????  ??????  ??????  ??????
>   Prudence is of the mind, is not prone of verification, is its own verification.
>   Serves to all degrees and entities and classes and is satisfied.
>   Is the safety of the actuality and everlastingness of objects, and the superbness of objects.
>   Something there is in the raft of the glance of objects that teases it out of the mind.

Comment: To confirm: the question marks indicate the number of words in the line, but not the number of letters of each word?

Comment: @QuestionAsker: the question marks just indicate the line, but not concrete words.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It can be

> Wisdom cannot be pass’d from one having it to another not having it, from Walt Whitman's Song of the Open Road.

See: http://www.poetryfoundation.org/poem/178711

> Here is the test of wisdom,
>   Wisdom is not finally tested in schools,
>   **Wisdom cannot be pass’d from one having it to another not having it,**
>   Wisdom is of the soul, is not susceptible of proof, is its own proof,
>   Applies to all stages and objects and qualities and is content,
>   Is the certainty of the reality and immortality of things, and the excellence of things;
>   Something there is in the float of the sight of things that provokes it out of the soul.

Answer (score 3):

This reminded me of

> [1 Corinthians 13](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Corinthians%2013)

I don't have an answer yet, though.

Comment: I would have said Proverbs 4.

Comment: Yeah, Wisdom corresponds much better to Prudence than Charity does.  Something about the structure is what reminded me of the Corinthians passage, though.